# restricting area of UV project to projector plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, modifiers

I am trying to model a Rummikub tile (well, game eventually) as my first blender project. The tiles are basically a rectangular cube with a dimple where the number is printed.

[image: actual tiles]

I created a tile with a dimple by using a boolean difference modifier. I'm now trying to UV project a face (number or joker) onto the tile using a plane from above as the projector. I can't figure out how to restrict the texture to be limited to the size of the projector plane.

[image: bad tile]

Here is what my node graph and modifiers look like:
[image: cycles material]

I should say that the goal is to place the face in the middle of the dimple, if there is a better way than a UV project then let me know. Ideally I could control both the color of the tile and just use some sort of stencil mask for the face shape. So any pointers along those lines would be appreciated as well.

Here is my file and texture
[image]

[image: texture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orientation, scale and position of the projector will influence the UV project modifier.

So, starting from your configuration (I changed nothing except limiting the rendering of the plane to wire), simply scale and grab the projector.

[image]

About a 'better way' to do it. I don't know if it is a better way, but you can get rid of the UV Project modifier defining a UV map for the sphere, because the UV of the sphere will be inherited by the tile during the Boolean modifier operation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had tried translating the plane down but didn't scale it. I had originally sized the plane the size of the "13" that I was intending to be projected. I was hoping I could make the projection orthographic so the size would correspond with the plane's size.

Comment: @BenMabey, it is orthographic, so translating down (along Z of the object) does nothing.